# How draw a rectangle/hole in a "Form3" using coordinates of a PaintBox present in "Form2"?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, mouse-coordinates, tscrollbox, paintbox

I have a "**Form2**" that have a `ScrollBox` and a `PaintBox`.

Also exists another Form called "**Form3**" (also with a `PaintBox` inside) that have the `ScrollBox` of **"Form2"** as your parent. Then i need draw a **rectangle** => **hole** over **"Form3"** based on coordinates of `Form2.PaintBox`.

This is possible?

Thanks in advance by any suggestion/help.

---

[image]

**Form1**:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;

end.
```

**Form2**:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    Button2: TButton;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    Button3: TButton;
    PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

uses
  Unit3;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form3.Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TOpenDialog.Create(self) do
    try
      Caption := 'Open Image';
      Options := [ofPathMustExist, ofFileMustExist];
      if Execute then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form3 := TForm3.Create(self);
  Form3.Parent := ScrollBox1;
  Form3.Show;
end;
```

**Form3**:

```
type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FSelecting: Boolean;
    FSelection: TRect;
    pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4: Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

uses
  Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Left := (Form2.Image1.Width - Width) div 2;
  Top := (Form2.Image1.Height - Height) div 2;
end;

procedure TForm3.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FSelection.Left := X;
  FSelection.Top := Y;
  FSelecting := True;
end;

procedure TForm3.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelection.Right := X;
    FSelection.Bottom := Y;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  FormRegion: HRGN;
  HoleRegion: HRGN;
begin
  FSelecting := False;
  FSelection.Right := X;
  FSelection.Bottom := Y;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;

  pos1 := FSelection.Left;
  pos2 := FSelection.Top;
  pos3 := X;
  pos4 := Y;

  FSelection.NormalizeRect;
  if FSelection.IsEmpty then
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, 0, True)
  else
  begin
    FormRegion := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height);
    HoleRegion := CreateRectRgn(pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4);
    CombineRgn(FormRegion, FormRegion, HoleRegion, RGN_DIFF);
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, FormRegion, True);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlue;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection)
end;
```

Form2 **.DFM**:

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 478
  ClientWidth = 767
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 767
    Height = 47
    Align = alTop
    TabOrder = 0
    object Button1: TButton
      Left = 24
      Top = 8
      Width = 89
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Form3 Open'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = Button1Click
    end
    object Button2: TButton
      Left = 119
      Top = 8
      Width = 89
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Form3 Close'
      TabOrder = 1
      OnClick = Button2Click
    end
    object Button3: TButton
      Left = 232
      Top = 8
      Width = 89
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Open image'
      TabOrder = 2
      OnClick = Button3Click
    end
  end
  object ScrollBox1: TScrollBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 47
    Width = 767
    Height = 431
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 1
    object Image1: TImage
      Left = 3
      Top = 4
      Width = 558
      Height = 301
      AutoSize = True
    end
    object PaintBox1: TPaintBox
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 763
      Height = 427
      Align = alClient
      ExplicitLeft = 80
      ExplicitTop = 40
      ExplicitWidth = 105
      ExplicitHeight = 105
    end
  end
  object OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog
    Left = 360
  end
end
```

Form3 **.DFM**:

```
object Form3: TForm3
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderStyle = bsNone
  Caption = 'Form3'
  ClientHeight = 365
  ClientWidth = 533
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poDefaultSizeOnly
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object PaintBox1: TPaintBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 533
    Height = 365
    Align = alClient
    OnMouseDown = PaintBox1MouseDown
    OnMouseMove = PaintBox1MouseMove
    OnMouseUp = PaintBox1MouseUp
    OnPaint = PaintBox1Paint
    ExplicitLeft = 328
    ExplicitTop = 200
    ExplicitWidth = 105
    ExplicitHeight = 105
  end
end
```

---

**EDITION:**

> *This question is basically a continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949578/how-align-a-same-form-in-client-side-and-server-side-respectively)*

Comment: How does this question differ from your previous one?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, my goal is follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949578/how-align-a-same-form-in-client-side-and-server-side-respectively?noredirect=1#comment94794811_53949578), since that i'm able to see behind "Form3" and send the rectangle to client in `Form2.PaintBox` coordinates (like i'm making before), the lose of transparency in "Form3" that made me choose this alternative.

Comment: OK. How does this question differ from your previous one?

Comment: The goal is align "Form3" in server and client, but since that also can be possible make what i said on previous comment. `Form3.Parent := Form2.ScrollBox` was the suggestion. You have another?

Comment: Never mind. It seems we are talking at cross purposes.

Comment: The question is clear, but you not understood nothing.

Comment: The question looks the same as your previous one. How to relate coordinates in two different forms. I asked you a simple question. You seem evasive. How does this question differ from your previous one?

Comment: Then, i'm searching something to solve this, what was suggested (`Form3.Server.Parent := Form2.Server.ScrollBox`) on previous question, lose the transparency of "Form3.Server" that i need. This is the unique solution?

Comment: Then this present question here, is a attempt to follow what was suggested. In my opinion, making a rectangle/hole on `Form3.Server` in `Form2.Server.PaintBox` coordinates, this can imitate like how i made before the suggestion (`Form3.Server.Parent := Form2.Server.ScrollBox`).

Comment: I don't see an answer to my question. I concede.

Comment: If this question seems the same previous to you, then why you not answerd the previous (if have a solution)?

Comment: **PS:**: Again, *`This present question here, is a attempt to follow what was suggested, but based in my necessity.`* only this :-)

Comment: Never mind. If you don't know whether or not this question is the same as the previous, then this can't be constructive.

Comment: Lucas, I see I wasn't fully clear in my writing about parenting `Form3` to `Form2` in your earlier post. As a continuation I meant to say: To avoid loosing transparency, let `Form3` be free floating (unparented) and use regions to clip it to the area of `Form2.ScrollBox`, so it doesn't float over outside of the scrollbox. Luckily you are already using regions, so it should be easy to adopt.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, then you is saying that `Form3.Server.Parent := Form2.Server.ScrollBox` not is more a solution? or still is? because this i not understood this part *`To avoid loosing transparency, let Form3 be free floating (unparented) and use regions to clip it to the area of Form2.ScrollBox`* <= this must be with `Parent` (like you said before) or no?

Comment: I will happy, if you can gove a answer with a code example about this.

Comment: If, as I have understood it, `Form3` must be semitransparent, don't parent it to `Form2`. Instead, let it be free floating, above everything else and use regions to clip it to be visible only within the area of `Form2.ScrollBox`.

Comment: I will try to get the time for an example

Comment: From where did the need for the paintboxes suddenly appear? They were not there before.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, i had added 1 `PaintBox` in **Server.Form3** to draw, already that i had lost transparency and not was possible draw (behind `Server.Form3`) in `Server.Form2.PaintBox` anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a testapp to demonstrate alignment of `Server.Form3` with `Client.Form3` in the image of "client" side.

First `Form2`. It's the main form in this testapp. It has a scrollbox and in that an image (the image of the "client" side), here represented by a 1000 x 400 brickwall. The image has a green rectangle centered vertically and horisontally, mimicing the `Form3` visible on the client side.

```
type
  TScrollBox = class(Vcl.forms.TScrollBox) // we need to handle scroll events
  protected
    procedure WMHScroll(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_HSCROLL;
    procedure WMVScroll(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_VSCROLL;
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    Image1: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBox1Resize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected                                 // we also need to react to form moves   
    procedure WMWindowPosChanged(var Msg: TWMWindowPosChanged); message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

// a helper function
function fnMyRgn(HostControl: TWinControl; Form: TForm): HRGN;
begin
  result := CreateRectRgn(
    (HostControl.ClientOrigin.X - Form.Left),
    (HostControl.ClientOrigin.Y - Form.Top),
    (HostControl.ClientOrigin.X - Form.Left + HostControl.ClientWidth),
    (HostControl.ClientOrigin.Y - Form.Top + HostControl.ClientHeight));
end;

// Note how Form3 is centered to the scrollbox content (the image) by using scrollbar ranges
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rgn: HRGN;
begin
  Form3 := TForm3.Create(self);

  Form3.Left := ScrollBox1.ClientOrigin.X - ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Position +
    (ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Range - Form3.Width) div 2;

  Form3.Top  := ScrollBox1.ClientOrigin.Y - ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position +
    (ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Range - Form3.Height) div 2;

  rgn := fnMyRgn(ScrollBox1, Form3);
  if 0 = SetWindowRgn(Form3.Handle, rgn, True) then
    DeleteObject(rgn);

  Form3.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form3.Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form3.AlphaBlend := False;
  Form3.TransparentColor := True;
end;

// Scrollbox is anchored to all sides of the form,
// ergo, size changes if form size changes
procedure TForm2.ScrollBox1Resize(Sender: TObject);
var
  ScrBox: TScrollBox;
  rgn: hRgn;
begin
  if Form3 = nil then exit;

  ScrBox := Sender as TScrollBox;

  Form3.Left := ScrBox.ClientOrigin.X - ScrBox.HorzScrollBar.Position +
    (ScrBox.HorzScrollBar.Range - Form3.Width) div 2;

  Form3.Top  := ScrBox.ClientOrigin.Y - ScrBox.VertScrollBar.Position +
    (ScrBox.VertScrollBar.Range - Form3.Height) div 2;

  rgn := fnMyRgn(ScrBox, Form3);
  if 0 = SetWindowRgn(Form3.Handle, rgn, True)then
    DeleteObject(rgn);
end;

// Form3 must be moved if Form2 is moved
procedure TForm2.WMWindowPosChanged(var Msg: TWMWindowPosChanged);
begin
  inherited;

  if Form3 = nil then exit;

  Form3.Left := ScrollBox1.ClientOrigin.X - ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Position +
    (ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Range - Form3.Width) div 2;

  Form3.Top  := ScrollBox1.ClientOrigin.Y - ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position +
    (ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Range - Form3.Height) div 2;
end;

{ TScrollBox }

procedure TScrollBox.WMHScroll(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  rgn: hRgn;
begin
  inherited;
  if Form3 = nil then exit;

  Form3.Left := self.ClientOrigin.X - HorzScrollBar.Position +
    (HorzScrollBar.Range - Form3.Width) div 2;

  rgn := fnMyRgn(self, Form3);
  if 0 = SetWindowRgn(Form3.Handle, rgn, True) then
    DeleteObject(rgn);
end;

procedure TScrollBox.WMVScroll(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  rgn: hRgn;
begin
  inherited;
  if Form3 = nil then exit;

  Form3.Top := self.ClientOrigin.Y - VertScrollBar.Position +
    (VertScrollBar.Range - Form3.Height) div 2;

  rgn := fnMyRgn(self, Form3);
  if 0 = SetWindowRgn(Form3.Handle, rgn, True) then
    DeleteObject(rgn);
end;

end.
```

Then we have `Form3`, which here is just a 400 wide x 300 high borderless form with a couple of buttons and a red drawn outline. It can be alphablended or fully transparent. It is set to alphablended with blend value of 127. When `Form2.Button3` is clicked it switches to transparent. The yellow fill color is the `TransparentColoValue`

```
type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

procedure TForm3.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  Canvas.Rectangle(1, 1, clientwidth-1, clientheight-1);
end;
```

First screenshot shows `Form2` only

[image]

Second image shows `Form2` with `Form3` as alphablended, slightly scrolled

[image]

And the third image shows `Form2` with `Form3` as transparent, further scrolled

[image]

Now that `Client.Form3` is centered to the screen of the client and `Server.Form3` is centered to the image of the client screen, any holes you draw with the same coordinates, should coincide.

Note also that I used a `TImage` in the scrollbox according your first question, because I don't really understand why you would change to a paintbox. It would however, not be a problem to use a paintbox instead of the `TImage`, if you prefer that.

As requested, added the background image used

[image]

Comment: *`Note also that I used a TImage in the scrollbox according your first question, because I don't really understand why you would change to a paintbox. It would however, not be a problem to use a paintbox instead of the TImage, if you prefer that.`* **PaintBox** was used only to draw (with mouse), the rectangle in `Server.Form2` through of `Server.Form3` transparent.

Comment: Ok, I didn't reread the previous question, and remembered wrong, but as I said, you can use a `TPaintBox` instead of the `TImage`.

Comment: could upload of *`"The image has a green rectangle centered"`* please? i want execute your code example of answer more near of how you made.